# File Renaming in HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop, cron, cloudera

i am putting a particular file in hdfs directory with name A1 and want to do this process multiple times while running my shell script, but when i put the file in hdfs directory i want to rename that A1 file and every time renaming should be different how can i do this .

**scenario**: I am having a file name A1 and once all the operation is done that file i am keeping in hdfs directory name completed_data, as i am running this using shell script and scheduler this process will happen after an interval that time i same file name A1 cannot exist in same directory so i want to rename A1 every time with different names.

Thanks

Comment: Rename with filename and timestamp or process id or some random number obtained from `/dev/random`

Comment: can you write the command as it would help me to understand better.

Comment: hadoop fs -mv A1 A1+$RANDOM  use this to rename the file and copy the new A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving examples of normal `mv`. You can change it for your hadoop environment.

Using $RANDOM (as commented by @Backtrack ):

```
mv A1 A1_${RANDOM}
```

Using `date` command:

```
mv A1 A1_$(date +%N)
```

Using `mktemp`:

```
mv A1 $(mktemp --tmpdir=/dir/where/you/want A1_XXX)
```